# Filter out exact portion of string that contains special characters bash

Tags: regex, bash, macos, awk, sed

I’m trying to write a command in bash (on Mac OS 10.12) to filter out a portion of a string that contains special characters:

The portion of the string to be removed is:

```
,MYDOMAIN\sct_DesktopAdmin
```

An example of what I want is:

Initial string:

```
domain admins,enterprise admins,MYDOMAIN\sct_DesktopAdmin,MYDOMAIN\sct_LocalAdmins
```

Final string after filtering:

```
domain admins,enterprise admins,MYDOMAIN\sct_LocalAdmins
```

Because the initial string will vary from machine to machine it is important that the filter is an exact match to this portion only.

I’ve been trying to create something with sed but have so far only produces filters that remove all the special characters and my attempts at escaping the individual special characters have not worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please elaborate your problem more clearly, it is NOT cleat at all. Try to make it simple by posting simple sample input and sample output in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring replacement (replacing `MYDOMAIN\sct_DesktopAdmin,` with an empty string):

```
str="domain admins,enterprise admins,MYDOMAIN\sct_DesktopAdmin, MYDOMAIN\sct_LocalAdmins"
printf "${str/MYDOMAIN\\sct_DesktopAdmin, }\n"
```

Edit: remove second `/` thanks to Toby Speight, use `printf` instead of `echo`, add space at the end to conform to OP edit

Comment: Thanks, that works. That's great.

Comment: As the replacement is an empty string, you're allowed to omit the second `/`.

Comment: Out of interest, can anyone advise on the syntax to do this with sed?

Comment: @ethamoose using sed: `printf "$str\n" | sed 's/MYDOMAIN\\sct_DesktopAdmin, //'`

Comment: Many thanks. For some reason, I thought it was going to be more complicated than that. I thought that you had to escape the , as well.